# Custom train-test split using two stratified classes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use NLP techniques to predict the mental status of patients at the time doctor's notes were taken. I have two classes, suffix (multilabel) as well as mental_status (binary, Lucid or Delirium). I am trying to build train and test sets from a reduced list that meet the following specifications:

- Shared unique suffix list
- For each set for each suffix, at least one row for Lucid *and* Delirium

Any imbalances I will correct with sample weights (I am only trying to predict mental_status, but I need the data to also be balanced on suffix). I just need at least one row for each combination within the full Cartesian product of suffixes and mental_statuses.

For example, in the dataset below, only the DWM Communication suffixes would make it into the train-test split.

```
suffix              mental_status
DWN Communication   Lucid
DWN Communication   Delirium
DWN Communication   Lucid
DWN Communication   Delirium
DWN Communication   Lucid
DWN Psychiatry      Lucid
DWN Psychiatry      Delirium
DWN Psychiatry      Delirium
DWN Cardio stuff    Lucid
DWN Cardio stuff    Delirium
DWN Blood .....     Lucid
DWN Blood .....     Lucid
DWN Blood .....     Lucid
```

The output I would want for the example above for train would be

```
DWN Communication   Lucid
DWN Communication   Delirium
DWN Communication   Lucid
```

and test

```
DWN Communication   Lucid
DWN Communication   Delirium
```

I've tried

```
df.groupby(['suffix','mental_status']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

but it doesn't ensure there is one of each Delirium and Lucid for each suffix.

As another example,

```
    suf ms
11  blood   delirium
15  blood   delirium
0   blood   lucid
1   blood   lucid
5   blood   lucid
6   blood   lucid
10  blood   lucid
16  blood   lucid
3   psych   delirium
19  psych   delirium
4   psych   lucid
8   psych   lucid
9   psych   lucid
13  psych   lucid
14  psych   lucid
18  psych   lucid
7   stool   delirium
2   stool   lucid
12  stool   lucid
17  stool   lucid
```

would be split into

```
    suf ms
11  blood   delirium
0   blood   lucid
1   blood   lucid
5   blood   lucid
6   blood   lucid
3   psych   delirium
4   psych   lucid
8   psych   lucid
9   psych   lucid
13  psych   lucid
```

and

```
    suf ms
15  blood   delirium
10  blood   lucid
16  blood   lucid
19  psych   delirium
14  psych   lucid
18  psych   lucid
```

Edit:

I think I arrived at a solution:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
def custom_split(df, test_size):
    f = lambda ms: (
        df[df.mental_status==ms]
        .groupby('suffix')
        .filter(lambda x:len(x)>=1/min(test_size,1-test_size))
        .suffix
    )
    delirium = f('Delirium')
    lucid = f('Lucid')
    valid_suffixes = set(delirium).intersection(lucid)
    df = df[df.suffix.isin(valid_suffixes)]
    df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df,test_size,random_state=9,
                                         stratify=df.mental_status+df.suffix)
    return df_train, df_test
```

Comment: Will you please make a sample dataframe containing your expected output to help visualize?

Comment: Are there columns that you are not showing or is this it?

Comment: Also how would you split psychiatry? There’s only 3 and an uneven number of lucid and delirium

Comment: There are other columns, but they shouldn't matter for the purposes of my question. The splits themselves really dont matter (just put "a lot more" in train than test) - I just need to have everything stratified without making it so any suffix has lucid but not delirium (or vice versa) in either train or test.

Comment: So you’re saying, only if there’s an even number of lucid and delirium under each suffix, then you will do a split, right?

Comment: It doesn't matter if they're even. Only if there's at least one lucid and delirium under each suffix. I'll clarify my example.

Comment: I see but you can’t split psychiatry because in one group or the other you will only have delirium without lucid correct?

Comment: Bingo. That's the crux of the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241807/discussion-between-chris-coffee-and-anarchy).

Answer (score 1):

what about using the index and `duplicated(keep=False)`?

```
test = df[~df.duplicated(keep=False)]
output  = df.drop_duplicates()
output = output[~output.index.isin(test.index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you just do `df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)`? It looks like that’s all there is to it because you just want the unique values based on the combination of both columns.

Comment: It would, except I want to hold onto the duplicates. I just want to drop those that don't have duplicates.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your desired output @ChrisCoffee

Comment: I updated the question with an example. Please let me know if you need me to elaborate or give a bigger example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mask filter:

```py
mask = df["DWN" in df['suffix']]
df = df[mask]
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

use Groupby

```
data="""index,suf,ms
11,blood,delirium
15,blood,delirium
0,blood,lucid
1,blood,lucid
5,blood,lucid
6,blood,lucid
10,blood,lucid
16,blood,lucid
3,psych,delirium
19,psych,delirium
4,psych,lucid
8,psych,lucid
9,psych,lucid
13,psych,lucid
14,psych,lucid
18,psych,lucid
7,stool,delirium
2,stool,lucid
12,stool,lucid
17,stool,lucid"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',')
#print(df)
lst=[]
grouped=df.groupby(['suf','ms'])
for group in grouped.groups:
    lst.append(group)
    
print(lst)
```

output:

```
[('blood', 'delirium'), ('blood', 'lucid'), ('psych', 'delirium'), ('psych', 'lucid'), ('stool', 'delirium'), ('stool', 'lucid')]
```

you can now use the tuples as filters

Comment: That would work in this example, but my dataset contains many suffixes that don't follow any pattern cleanly.

Comment: Hospital doctor's notes.